# Eliminate query terms based on their document frequency

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

How can we configure elastic search to eliminate query terms specific to field based on document frequency threshold?

for eg:  for query "title:test AND title:west AND desc:world AND desc:hello"
Assume document frequency threshold is set to 10 and few terms in the query i.e, desc:world and title:test have document frequency greater than 10, i.e query should be changed to "title:west AND desc:hello".

one approach is to query for each terms in the and based on retrieved document count eliminate such terms exceeding the given document frequency threshold, but this is not effective as it increases number of searches drastically!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do that in elasticsearch, but Lucene provides the `QueryAutoStopWordAnalyzer`, which does something pretty close.

Have a look at http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_3/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/query/QueryAutoStopWordAnalyzer.html